# ValueError: time data '12/31/2017' does not match format '%d-%m-%Y'

Tags: python, datetime, datetime-format

I am processing date data and can't see an answer to the error as the format does match my date data:

"12/31/2017"

"12/31/2017"

"1/1/2018"

"1/1/2018"

"1/1/2018"

"1/1/2018"

But when I try to convert I get this error

```
ValueError: time data '12/31/2017' does not match format '%d-%m-%Y'
```

I have tried switching the %m-%d around just to test but still get the same error.

This is my code for trying to convert the date data:

```
from datetime import datetime
data.Date = data.Date.apply(lambda x:datetime.strptime(x, '%m-%d-%Y'))
```

If somebody gives me a clue how to resolve this, any help would be greatly appreciated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`12/31/2017` is in the format `M/D/Y`, since you can't have months with value `31` :)

Also, you are forgetting to account for the forward slashes. Try this:

```py
from datetime import datetime
data.Date = data.Date.apply(lambda x:datetime.strptime(x, '%m/%d/%Y'))
```

Comment: Cheers Luca. Knew it would be something simple I was missing. Much obliged!

Comment: @BrianC Awesome, glad to be of assistance! By the way, please don't forget to mark this as the correct answer if you think it helped you solving your question, just so people can refer to it in the future :) Cheers!